# url rewriting in iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am running IIS7.5 and the URL Rewrite module.

I followed these step by step instructions to enable user friendly URL's:

> [Rule Templates for the URL Rewrite Module - User Friendly URL - rule template](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/497/user-friendly-url---rule-template/)

If I enter the URL `http://domain.com/default/` instead of `http://domain.com/default.aspx` the website throws `404: file not found error`.

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^demourl\.dev\.asenetechdev1\.com/default\.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="demourl.dev.asenetechdev1.com/default" 
              appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^demourl\.dev\.asenetechdev1\.com/default$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="false" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="demourl.dev.asenetechdev1.com/default.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
      <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img"
             pattern="^(.*)demourl\.dev\.asenetechdev1\.com/default\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}/ demourl.dev.asenetechdev1.com/default" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

I also tried using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter with this. But I am able to generate friendly urls on local as well as on server, but I want extensionless url, which is working ok on my local server, but not on the live server.

Comment: You forgot to include your `web.config` settings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is currently not matching /default/. It is only matching /default

Changing

```
<match url="^demourl\.dev\.asenetechdev1\.com/default$" />
```

to

```
<match url="^demourl\.dev\.asenetechdev1\.com/default/{0,1}$" />
```

should do it.